# Highlight only newly added lines when the Emacs buffer is auto-reverted

Tags: emacs, buffer, hook, revert

I do have an Emacs command which adds a separator line, in log files, when there is more than 3 seconds between timestamps found on 2 consecutive lines:

```
(defun log-mode-display-separator-line ()
  "Separate blocks of log lines with an horizontal line."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let (last ov)
      (while (re-search-forward "[0-9]\\{4\\}-[01][1-9]-[0-3][0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" nil t)
        (when last
          (when (> (- (float-time (date-to-time (match-string 0)))
                      (float-time (date-to-time last)))
                   3)
            (setq ov (make-overlay (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))
            (overlay-put ov 'face 'log-mode-separator-face)))
        (setq last (match-string 0))))))
```

The `log-mode-separator-face` uses the overline attribute to visually put an horizontal line between "semantic" blocks of lines.

I would like to get that horizontal line automatically inserted when the buffer is reverted (every 5 seconds), but the processing may become too big on huge log files, which are constantly updated.  As of now, the whole file is scanned from the beginning each time we call that command...

How can I realize this, then?  (With Emacs, no doubt it is...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's no guarantee that the buffer is reverted every 5 seconds. Since Emacs 24.4, autorevert uses file notifications, that means the buffer is reverted whenever the file changes on disk. If you want to suppress this, set `auto-revert-use-notify` to nil.

Further on, it depends how you want to revert your log file. I suppose you use `auto-revert-tail-mode`. This mode calls the hook functions contained in `before-revert-hook` and `after-revert-hook`. As a strategy, I would write a function for `after-revert-hook`, which underlines the last line in your buffer to be reverted. Something like this:

```
(defun my-auto-revert-tail-mode-display-separator-line ()
  "Separate blocks of log lines with an horizontal line."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (while (and (= (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))
        (> (point) (point-min)))
      (forward-line -1))
    (let ((ov (make-overlay (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))))
      (overlay-put ov 'face 'underline))))

(add-hook 'after-revert-hook 'my-auto-revert-tail-mode-display-separator-line)
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposition. For your information, I do already have auto-revert-use-notify set to nil - on my Cygwin Emacs (on Windows). Though, I've enabled global-auto-revert-mode.

Comment: Now, regarding your solution, the fact is I really want to insert a line only if the timestamp between 2 consecutive lines is higher than 3 seconds. Some operations can take 1 or 2 seconds, and the revert can happen in between, though I don't want an horizontal line to show up. Only if there is 3 seconds between 2 timestamps - which corresponds then to a different user request.

Comment: Somehow, when the buffer is reverted, my above function should be able to "restart" only from the list line before the revert, up to the new end of the buffer. Then, it would only be able to highlight the desired lines.

Comment: You have `before-revert-hook` and `after-revert-hook`. Declare a global variable which keeps the timestamp of the last marked line. In `before-revert-hook`, remember the point something is added. In `after-revert-hook`, start parsing the lines from the point remembered in `before-revert-hook`. If there is a line with more than 3 seconds span, highlight with `overline`.

Comment: This seems to be the right thing to do... I'll try it, and will post the solution once it works. Thanks!